# PHP Array, remove only duplicates next to eachother

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array(1, 2, '...', '...', '...', 6, 7, 8, '...', 10);
array_unique creates: array(1, 2, '...', 6, 7, 8, 10);
I want the following: array(1, 2, '...', 6, 7, 8, '...', 10);
```

So basically, I'm looking for a fast way to remove only duplicates next to eachother.

Comment: AFAIK, no out of the box function for it, so write a small looping script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
$first = true;
foreach ($array as $x) {
    if ($first || $x !== $previous) $result[] = $x;
    $previous = $x;
    $first = false;
}
```

Alter the `$x !== $previous` condition to suit your preferred definition of "duplicate". For example, `array_unique` does a loosely-typed comparison.

Comment: You need to set `$first` back to `true` when you encounter a non-duplicate.

Comment: @Barmar No, that's not what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
<?php

$arr = array(1, 2, '...', '...', '...', 6, 7, 8, '...', 10);

$el = $arr[0];

$out = $arr;

for ($i=1, $c = count($out); $i<$c; ++$i) {
    if ($arr[$i] == $el) {
        unset($out[$i]);
    }
    else {
        $el = $out[$i];
    }
}

$out = array_values($out);

foreach ($out as $i) {
    echo $i."<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
...
6
7
8
...
10
```